# How are dot relative paths and rootDir paths treated differently in my project's jest configuration?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

## Problem Description

I have a question about the `jest.config.ts` that I am setting up.
There I use a `moduleNameMapper`, so that imports a la `import ... from "@base/..."` also work in the tests. For this I use a function of `ts-jest`, which returns the corresponding regular expressions from the `tsconfig.json.compilerOptions.paths`. `tsconfig.json` is a json file which I am importing with typescript's `resolveJsonModule` option. See [here for the documentation on moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring).

The function from `ts-jest` returns one of the following two objects to be used as the `moduleNameWrapper`, depending on other parameters passed. How that works is not relevant for the question, as I am also able to just enter the keys and values directly, not using the `ts-jest` function.

First Object: `{ '^@base/(.*)$': './src/$1' }`
Second Object: `{ '^@base/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1' }`
The first does not work (the modules are then not resolved), the second works correctly.

### Question

**Hence my question:** What does `.` mean as a path for jest? What is the difference with `<rootDir>`? Why do they both not point to the same directory? My jest config is in the root directory of the project, so *I would assume that* both `.` and `<rootDir` would point to the root directory (the folder where the jest config is located). Also see [the documentation for rootDir](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#rootdir-string).

## What I've tried so far

I tried putting both objects in as `moduleNameWrapper` in the jest.config, but only the one with `rootDir` worked. I would have expected `./src/$1` to have worked as well, but it did not.

The rootDir solution is unsatisfying, as producing the object including `<rootDir>` requires an additional options parameter, which sets a prefix. This prefix is hard coded, and could e.g. result in problems further in this project or when using this project as a foundation for the next.

This is the call to create the moduleNameMapper object via `ts-jest`:

```
pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {prefix: "<rootDir>/src/"}),
```

If the second parameter is omitted, then the dot version is produced, which does not work.

Thanks.